# Accessing servers through hostname now requires FQDN?

Tags: hostname, fqdn

After upgrading to Linux Mint 20, the servers (pgsql databases and windows network share) on our internal network now require the fully qualified domain instead of just the machine name.

For example, I used to be able to connect through simply px-data01-d but now need px-data01-d.dpsnetwork.org.

This is a huge headache as we have hundreds of projects that referenced the hostname, not the FQDN.

Nothing has changed on the network, and my Windows machine is still using the hostname.

Our former database administrator who uses Linux mentioned at one point a way of telling your machine to search differently for how it accesses servers on the network, and I see there is the /etc/hosts file as well, but I don't know if that is the right approach.

Comment: That short name is not the same as the part of the FQDN. Did you make a typo? Of course using the FQDN is best practice and that should have been happening all along. It's easy enough to fix.

Comment: @MichaelHampton sorry, that was a typo - if it is best to use the FQDN then we'll have to bite the bullet and fix them as we go, but just wondering if there was a fix such as the one our old DBA was suggesting... thx!

Comment: If your search domain is still in `/etc/hosts` then it should be working.

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok that worked - I hadn't come across using the /etc/hosts file before. If that isn't a redundant question on this forum, please add it as an answer and I'll accept it... thank you!!